# Django change static folder name to assets

Tags: python, django

I want to have following structure:

```
my_project
  my_app
     assets
       1.css
```

in my base.html I include css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/1.css" />
```

I tried to  change setting.py like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

and like this:

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     "/assets/",
 ]
```

But I still get the error that 1.css not found

Comment: Make sure cache is disabled in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add route into urls.py ?

Like:

```
 from django.conf.urls.static import static
 ulrpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL in `base.css` is relative, and is relative to the final URL of the rendered page. If that page appears as `example.com/pages/mypage.html`, the browser will look in `pages/assets/1.css`, which doesn't exist.

Try an absolute URL from the root:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/1.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
]
```

also it is possible to change the URL only... not the Directory

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
```

Load `{% load staticfiles %}` in your template and add

```
<link href="{% static '1.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```